# Why did the Torah require 7 days for sitting in the Succah but just 1 day for 4 minim?

Tags: sukkah, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

Is there any meaning, symbolism or explanation why the Torah requires just 1 day for using the 4 species but 7 days to sit in the Succah? Offhand, it seems that sitting in the succah is "more important" than the 4 species, but I don't think that's the real reason.

Comment: The Torah aslo requires taking the Lulav for 7 days in the Mikdash

Comment: The Torah also only required eating Matza/Maror/Pesach on 1 day but prohibited Chametz for 7. You should see this article http://www.rambish.org.il/results.asp?SearchFunction=browse&SearchCode=BRW_INV&SearchRequest=35&SearchSort=&UserAction=record,&jump=5

Comment: Re the article: The zip folder seems to have been removed since then, but "[בעניין מצוות ימים טובים](http://asif.co.il/download/kitvey-et/alon%20shevut/alonshevut150/150yom_tov.html)" is currently available in full from the _Asif_ site, and [part 1](http://etzion.org.il/he/%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D-%E2%80%93-%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7-%D7%90) is also available from VBM Har-Etzyon itself. @DoubleAA

Answer (score 1):

Taking the four species is much more obviously a mitzvah than sitting outside in a hut. Thus, one could argue that to make it more noticeably a mitzvah, it was commanded for 7 days. See Guide for the Perplexed 3:49.

> The Feast of Weeks is the anniversary of the Revelation on Mount
>   Sinai. In order to raise the importance of this day, we count the days
>   that pass since the preceding festival, just as one who expects his
>   most intimate friend on a certain day counts the days and even the
>   hours. This is the reason why we count the days that pass since the
>   offering of the Omer, between the anniversary of our departure from
>   Egypt and the anniversary of the Lawgiving. The latter was the aim and
>   object of the exodus from Egypt, and thus God said, "I brought you
>   unto myself" (Exod. xix. 4). As that great revelation took place only
>   on one day, so we keep its anniversary only one day: but if the eating
>   of unleavened bread on Passover were only commanded for one day, we
>   should not have noticed it, and its object would not have been
>   manifest. For it frequently happens that we take the same kind of food
>   for two or three days. But by our continuing for a whole period [of
>   seven days] to eat unleavened bread, its object becomes clear and
>   evident.
>
> New-Year is likewise kept for one day; for it is a day of repentance,
>   on which we are stirred up from our forgetfulness. For this reason the
>   shofar is blown on this day, as we have shown in Mishneh-torah. The
>   day is, as it were, a preparation for and an introduction to the day
>   of the Fast, as is obvious from the national tradition about the days
>   between New-Year and the Day of Atonement.
>
> The Feast of Tabernacles, which is a feast of rejoicing and gladness,
>   is kept seven days, in order that the idea of the festival may be more
>   noticeable. (Friedlander translation)

As for the significance of specifically 7 days, Ralbag explains that many things in the Torah (including the days of Succos) are based on 7. The reason for this is that there are 7 levels of "existence" (that might not be the best word) and the seventh level is God. Thus the 7 days of Succos remind us of the holiness and separateness of God.

**Ralbag Joshua Chapter 6**

> והנה היה זה המספר לשביעיות ר"ל שהקיפו העיר שבעה ימים והיו שם שבעה
>   כהנים ושבעה שופרות היובלים וביום השביעי הקיפו העיר שבע פעמים [לסיבה
>   בעינה] שזכרנו במספר השבעה שזכרנו בתורה כמו השמיטה ושבעה שמטות ושבע
>   שבתות שהם שבעה ימים שבע פעמים ושבעה ימי הפסח ושבעה ימי סוכה

**Ralbag Exodus Chapter 20 The Tenth Lesson**

> והנה ימצא עוד תועלת בו בדעות והוא שכבר למדנו מענין השבת שבכאן לצורות
>   שבע מדרגות והמדרגה השביעית היא קדש והוא ה' יתעלה והם צורות היסודות והם
>   האיכויות כאילו תאמר החום והקור והלחות והיובש וצורות המתדמי־החלקים
>   המורכבים מהיסודות וצורות הצמחים וצורות הבעלי חיים וצורת האדם — והוא
>   השכל ההיולאני וצורות השכלים הנבדלים והצורה השביעית אשר שפעו ממנה כל
>   אלו הצורות היא ה' יתעלה והנה לשאר הצורות ימצא דבקות־מה בחומר ומלאכות
>   מיוחדות יסודרו מהם זולתי לה' יתעלה וזה כולו מבואר במעט עיון למי שעיין
>   בדברינו בחלק השלישי מהמאמר החמישי מספר מלחמות ה